# chaining logical operators - ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dictionary `dataframe_dict`consisting of over 1000 dataframes `dataframe_dict.items()`). Each dataframe represents data collected from a location (i.e. one dataframe for each location), and each dataframe has the same data columns (key).

Each dataframe looks like this

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4), columns = list('abcd')) 
df
          a         b         c         d
0  0.325799  0.731273  0.467031  0.177742
1  0.084133  0.271076  0.761092  0.067709
2  0.946860  0.606838  0.260437  0.094640
3  0.076870  0.450473  0.693679  0.760893
```

For each dataframe, I want to find out which column(s) has over 30% missing values, and identify those columns and store them in `reject_list`.

This is how I currently identify these columns

```
    reject_list =[]
    for key, item in dataframe_dict.items():
        if ((item[key].isnull().sum()) > (0.3*(len(item)))):
            reject_list.append(item[key])
            
            print('rejected due to more than 30% nulls: {}'.format(item[key]))
            
        item.dropna(inplace=True)
        item.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Python threw me this error on the logic

```
if ((item[key].isnull().sum()) > (0.3*(len(item)))):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1535, in __nonzero__
raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Looking at previous post I think I have created multiple series in this code where Boolean does not apply. How do I pass through this logic in this loop?

Comment: Look at `(item[key].isnull().sum()) > (0.3*(len(item))))` (by itself).  Is is one True/False value that `if` can act on, or is an Series of True/False values?  What's the `if` supposed to do with a Series?

Comment: @hpaulj it should return one True/False value per `item[key]`, and names of columns for those that are `True` (ie column that has more than 30% missing value)  will be stored in `reject_list`

Comment: Maybe try the `all()` method or `any()` if you dont care about all.

Comment: Assuming item to be a dataframe from your text, item[key] should be a Series.
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous suggests that item[key].isnull().sum() is a series indicating that item[key] is a DataFrame instead.
This happens when there are multiple columns in the frame with the same name.

Comment: The code is strange : in `(item[key].isnull().sum()) > (0.3*(len(item)))` , `key` is the key of the `item` dataframe in `dataframe_dict` which is apparently not necessary an `item` dataframe column name.

Comment: @hpchavaz can you give examples when `key` is not column name of `item`?

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

1. `for key, item in dataframe_dict.items():`assigns to `key` the key of a DATAFRAME_DICT element and to `ìtem` the corresponding dataframe,
2. In the loop body, you use `key` as if is the name of a column of the dataframe. But nothing assure that `key` is a column name but you did not provide how you build `dataframe_dict`

It looks like the for statement in your code is not should be the one for a loop that you did not provided and that the correct could something like `for col in item.columns` an example. It looks like you have a confusion on `key`.

The code below tries to resolve the confusion.

A question is if `reject_list` should be built on a dataframe merging all the dataframes in `dataframe_dict` or for each `dataframe_dict` element as your code implied. In the code below, `reject_list` build at the level of the `dataframe_dict` elements. But at the end of the process the `dataframe_dict` elements will probably not have the same columns.

```
reject_list =[]
for key, item in dataframe_dict.items():
    for col in item.columns:

        if ((item[col].isnull().sum()) > (0.3*(len(item)))):
            reject_list.append((key, col))

            print(f"In dataframe '{key}', column '{col}' rejected due to more than 30% null.")

            item.dropna(inplace=True)
            item.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```